# How to share one physical hard-disk to multiple KVM guest in a Proxmox VE?

Tags: virtualization, datastore, proxmox

I evaluate PROXMOX VE 2.0 to migrate a live server.

I have installed a server with the [PROXMOX VE](http://www.proxmox.com/) which hosts 4 KVM guests on two 300 GB HD's (RAID-1) and two 500 GB HD'a (RAID-1) as a data storage, which is .

1 UBUNTU 11.04 LTS based webservice application server VM-Client

1 UBUNTU 11.04 LTS based dynamic webproject server VM-Client

2 UBUNTU 11.04 LTS based MYSQL database server VM-Client

all those VM-Client's must have r/w access to the data storage (two 500 GB HD's RAID-1).

But I have now idea how I can fulfill these requirements, I don't know how I can add one or more partions of the data storage disk to multiple VM-Client's.

Comment: Do you have to use proxmox? This feature exists in oVirt out of the box, and in more than one possible way

Answer (score 1):

You may carve a disk from the host storage space and share it across VMs using 'sharable' flag. Here is a [link](http://humblec.com/how-to-share-a-disk-to-more-than-one-vm-using-libvirt-or-what-sharable-flag-do-in-libvirt/) that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that you could try would be to assign the storage to one of the VMs and make that VM be an NFS server (or add an additional VM that is just an NFS server).  The other VMs would be NFS clients.  This way you can still migrate the client VMs off of the host if you ever need to.

Answer (score 0):

You should share data storage via traditional NAS technologies (Samba, NFS), and service can be setup directly on Proxmox host.

Other options is using SAN technologies (iSCSI/AoE+GFS/OCFS2).

Finally, you could give GlusterFS or Ceph a try.